# Getting UnsupportedOperationException when i do HazelcastInstance.getConfig() from remote client

Tags: hazelcast

I Am using a Hazelcast java client(on node1), and creating Hazelcast maps on the different node(different laptop--node2).

My setup:
on node2 - Hazelcast is running.
on node1 - Stand -alone java program which acts like a Hazelcast java client.

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.getGroupConfig().setName("dev").setPassword("dev-pass");
config.addAddress("<node2-ip>:5701");
HazelcastInstance inst = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);

//Creating a mapconfig
MapConfig mcfg = new MapConfig();
mcfg.setName("democache");

//creating a mapstore config
MapStoreConfig mapStoreCfg = new MapStoreConfig();
mapStoreCfg.setClassName("com.main.MyMapStore").setEnabled(true);
```

MyMapStore is my implementation of Hazelcast MapStore. This class resides on

```
mcfg.setMapStoreConfig(mapStoreCfg);
**inst.getConfig()**.addMapConfig(mcfg);
```

I am getting "UnsupportedOperationException" when i run this code.. When i do inst.getConfig(), getting this exception.. Can anyone please let me know what is work around for this!

Stacktrace is:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.getConfig(HazelcastClient.java:144)
    at ClientClass.main(ClientClass.java:34)

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and correct your formatting.

Comment: Edited the post and added the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast clients can not access cluster nodes' configuration. This operation is unsupported.

Also you should not update/change configuration after cluster is up.

[UnsupportedOperationException, when doing HazelcastInstance.getConfig() from hazelcast client](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/hazelcast/amTi4Mlns0c/discussion)

Answer (score 0):

Client do not store data, so it does not use MapStore, so you should configure mapstore not on client, but the other hazelcast server instances. Like that:

```
        Config config = new Config();
        config.addMapConfig(mapconfig);
        HazelcastInstance node1 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
```